# Selecting an item from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to select the `Error` property the JSON returned from my AJAX request. This is the JSON:

```
{
    "Error": "Login",
    "Message": "Er zijn onjuiste inloggegevens ingevoerd! Probeer het opnieuw!"
}
```

I tried the following in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/cp/login.php',
    data: {
        u: $u, 
        p: $p, 
        t: $t, 
        r: $r, 
        s: $s
    },
    type: 'post',
    dateType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.Error);
    }
});
```

Which results in `undefined`.

Comment: Are you sure data is populated?

Comment: Yes, `data` results in the JSON above

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` to see what is received

Comment: @Ahmad I think that might be it. There's more data than only the JSON

Comment: Run these 2 statements in your success callback - `console.log(data); console.log( typeof data );`

Comment: You can use developer tools of your browser to monitor network requests and you can see the exact response from the server. This can be accessed usually by F12 shortcut key

Comment: Note that `dateType` should be `dataType`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for noticing

Comment: *"There's more data than only the JSON"* ....  then response is invalid if you send anything outside of `{}`

Comment: @charlietfl exactly. Problem found. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you don't want to handle errors in the success callback. There is also a Deprecation Notice in jQuery 3

> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are
>   removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and
>   jqXHR.always() instead.

This would mean you should handle your ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/cp/login.php',
    data: {
        u: $u, 
        p: $p, 
        t: $t, 
        r: $r, 
        s: $s
    },
    type: 'post',
    dateType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    // success
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
    // error
    console.log(data.Error);
  })
  .always(function() {
    // complete
  });
```

If this doesn't work the API is badly constructed, any API should implement proper response codes.

Comment: Are you trying to answer the question?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, the success should not be able to fetch the data.Error since it wasn't a successful operation if it returned an error. Note the first words in my reply "Typically you don't want to handle errors in the success callback"